# Web forms IDs with asp.net controls - need fixed values for external post

Tags: webforms

I have a form that collects payment information to be posted to a payment provider directly .. It cant enter our backend via a postback for security restrictions.

The payment provider server is expecting form values with given keys but of course webforms is messing  with the ids of controls based on their containing controls so the form parameters arent going match the  keys the payment provider is expecting…

Is there any way around this apart from using standard html controls right?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was solved using hidden fields. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebControls can be configured to output the identifier you specify using the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This can also be configured globally on [<pages> in web.config.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/950xf363(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExample" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" />
```